# How do I run this loop until there are no more objects in the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to run a while loop, but when the array reaches [], it crashes.

This is what I'm running:

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
let contas = require('./accounts');

let fila = []

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function main() {
  async function start(conta) {
    await sleep(1000);
    fila.logged = true;
    fila.shift();
  }

  async function queueStarter() {
    let loop = 1;
    if (fila.length >= loop && fila.length != 'undefined') {
      while (fila[0].logged == false) {
        start(fila[0]);
        await sleep(4000);
      }
    } else console.log('Reached array end')
  }

  for (key in contas) {
    let conta = contas[key];
    fila.push(conta);
  }
  queueStarter()
}
main();
```

This is the console:

```
PS C:\Users\Zwei\.vscode\IDKHowToCode> node .\StackExcample.js
C:\Users\Zwei\.vscode\IDKHowToCode\StackExcample.js:20
    while (fila[0].logged == false){
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logged')
    at queueStarter (C:\Users\Zwei\.vscode\IDKHowToCode\StackExcample.js:20:20)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

What I want is for it to stop when there are no more objects in the 'fila' array.

Why is it not stopping when it should?

Comment: `while (fila.length > 0 && !filea[0].logged)`?

Comment: `fila.length != 'undefined'` is always true. `.length` is a number, so it's never equal to a string. Did you mean `typeof filea.length != 'undefined`?

Comment: IDK who else commented a working fix for it but thanks to whoever it was an to you @Barmar, ```while (fila[0] && fila[0].logged == false){``` works like a charm <3

Comment: And you don't need the `if` statement.

Comment: Removed it, now it's just perfect, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmar suggested this fix and it works :D

on the queueStarter function, changing

`while (fila[0].logged == false) {`

to

`while (fila[0] && fila[0].logged == false){`

makes it check if there's something on fila[0] and if it's logged.

Comment: Assuming `fila` is an array, I personally would use `while (fila.length && fila[0].logged == false){ ... }` instead.  Just seems cleaner and more code-descriptive.